# Replacing a whole object within a specific array index with another object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following javascript object:

```
const myValidation = [
   {
       id:'1', name:'qqq', field1: 'Yes', field2: 'No', field3: 'Yes'
   }, 
   {
       id:'330', name:'www', field1: 'Yes', field2: 'Yes'
   }, 
   {
       id:'45', name:'eee', field1: 'Yes' 
   }
]
```

Based on some condition within my code and if it's `true`, I want to replace `myValidation[1]` index object with the following object and it will always be at array index 1:

```
const newObj = {
           id:'331', name:'tom', field1: 'Yes', field2: 'Yes', field3: 'Yes', field4: 'Yes'
      }
```

So after replacing the object, `myValidation` array now looks like:

```
const myValidation = [
   {
       id:'1', name:'qqq', field1: 'Yes', field2: 'No', field3: 'Yes'
   }, 
   {
       id:'331', name:'tom', field1: 'Yes', field2: 'Yes', field3: 'Yes', field4: 'Yes'
   }, 
   {
       id:'45', name:'eee', field1: 'Yes' 
   }
]
```

Please note that I don't want to match on ids or any other key, I purely want to replace an object with another object at `myValidation[1]` index.

Unsure how to achieve this.

Comment: You just assign the object. `myValidation[1] = { id:'331', name:'tom', field1: 'Yes', field2: 'Yes', field3: 'Yes', field4: 'Yes' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it's very simple, just access the object in your array and set it to the object that you want.

```
myValidation[1] = { key:'value', key2:'value2'....}
```

If you ever get to a point where you need to do this without knowing it's the specifically the object in the array at index 1, you could use `map` and `find` to achieve this aswell.